# Color of site icons on Stack Exchange Data Explorer is (not technically incorrect but) confusing

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

In the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), the icon color for the various sites *seems** incorrect: Whenever I select a main site, the icon is greyed out, and when ever I select the corresponding meta site, the icon is colored.

My initial instinct was to **think that the colors of the main/meta sites following the "Switch sites:" prompt should be switched**. (*Actually*, it seems like it's just a UI thing. See the edit below.)

---

***Edit:** Actually, the colors are technically not incorrect, since (as Jeremy Banks has pointed out) the icon shows "the other" site of the main/meta pair, and clicking on it is for switching to the respective other site. See the comment thread for some UI improvement ideas.

Comment: Where are you selecting them? The colors all appear to be correct for me.

Comment: The icon beside "switch sites" isn't the currently-selected site, it's a shortcut to switch between a site and its meta-site. [This has confused me many times, too](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1237738#1237738). The interface could probably do with a tweak.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I see. Two suggestions for a remedy / improvement: 1. Changing the text to "Switch between meta and main:" or "Switch to [corresponding] meta:"/"Switch to [corresponding] main:". 2. Switching the order of the icon and the "Switch sites:" text (and recoloring the icon to show the current site) might be very useful. Because this *is* confusing, even though one can argue that it's "technically" not wrong right now.

Comment: Displaying both `main` and `meta` site icons side-by-side might avoid confusion.

Comment: That has confused me many times too.

Comment: I was going to make the same question, and I saw yours (thought it was not possible that nobody had not seen this...:) ). I upvoted the question and all the comments (except the first one). It is really confusing the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created [this pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/110) to resolve the issue based on the suggestion made in the comments.

Here is what it will look like when you are running a query on Super User:

[image: switch to meta]

And here is what it will look like when you are running for  Meta Super User

[image: switch to main]

And this is what it will look like for sites without a Meta or Main site (currently only Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Apps I think):

[image: switch sites]

Am I missing a colon somewhere?

Either way: Allow for 6 to 8 weeks to get this reviewed, commented on, merged. Wait for a deployment of a revision > rev 2020.8.27.79.

Guess what happened? This is now deployed and live in rev 2020.12.13.80.